# Pass Response Object on $.mobile.changePage and access it on "pagebeforeshow"

Tags: jquery-mobile

how do we pass an object on $.mobile.changePage and access it on "pagebeforeshow" ???

I am using JQM 1.3.1 and jquery 1.9.1

```
$.mobile.changePage("Next.html", {data: RespObj});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#next", function(data) 

{
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

can anyone please help me figure this out. I am not able to access this data inside pagebefore show.

Comment: What version of JQM are you using ??, (pagebeforeshow) may be deprieacted for the one you are using. Also you need a selector i think where the (documnet) is. --- http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/

Answer (score 0):

As per I saw, I think you did some syntax mistake with the **pagebeforeshow** part.

**Change your code to the following one and check, hope it will work:**

#### Try this one

```
   $.mobile.changePage("Next.html#next", {data: RespObj});

   $(document).on("pagebeforeshow",function(data) 

           {
               alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           });
```

### If it works don't forget to VOTE

## Thank you and all the best